# gradle bootRun > Use test classpath

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

The problem I was having, was that I wanted to include test classpath resources in SpringBoot's `bootRun` gradle task. Why? So that I could use a `test` profile with test resources, to mock integration points.

**What I tried:**

- The [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications) only offers the `addResources = true` option (I tried using `customConfiguration` as per the similar [`bootRepackage` configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration), to no avail)
- No additional options are visible by looking at the [`BootRunTask` source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/run/BootRunTask.java)
- The equivalent [maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) has a plethora of options, including [`useTestClasspath`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#useTestClasspath) (which isn't mirrored in the gradle version)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across [the following solution](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot/archives/2016/02/15), which solved this issue for me.

Basically, the `BootRunTask` extends the standard `JavaExec` task, which offers a `classpath` option. So, you can add the test classpath resources by using the following gradle configuration:

```groovy
bootRun {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}
```